# PYTHONPATH on Linux

Tags: python, pythonpath

I'm novice in this, and I have started learning Python, but I have some questions that I'm not be able to understand,

1. What exactly is the PYTHONPATH (on Ubuntu)? Is it a folder?
2. Is Python provided by default on Ubuntu, or does it have to be installed explicitly?
3. Where is the folder in which all modules are (I have a lot folders called `python_`)?
4. If I wish a new module to work when I'm programming (such as pyopengl) where should I go to introduce all the folders I've got in the folder downloaded?
5. Coming back from the PYTHONPATH issue, how do I configure the PYTHONPATH in order to start working on my new module?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

1. `PYTHONPATH` is an [environment variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable)
2. Yes (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24802/on-which-unix-distributions-is-python-installed-as-part-of-the-default-install)
3. `/usr/lib/python2.7` on Ubuntu
4. you shouldn't install packages manually.  Instead, use [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip).  When a package isn't in pip, it usually has a [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) setup script which will install the package into the proper location (see point 3).
5. if you use pip or setuptools, then you don't need to set `PYTHONPATH` explicitly

If you look at the instructions for [pyopengl](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/installation.html), you'll see that they are consistent with points 4 and 5.

Answer (score 70):

1. `PYTHONPATH` is an environment variable which you can set to add additional directories where python will look for modules and packages.  e.g.:

   ```
   # make python look in the foo subdirectory of your home directory for   
   # modules and packages 
   export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${HOME}/foo
   ```

   Here I use the `sh` syntax.  For other shells (e.g. `csh`,`tcsh`), the syntax would be slightly different.  To make it permanent, set the variable in your shell's init file (usually ~/.bashrc).
2. Ubuntu comes with python already installed.  There may be reasons for installing other (independent) python versions, but I've found that to be rarely necessary.
3. The folder where your modules live is dependent on `PYTHONPATH` and where the directories were set up when python was installed.  For the most part, the installed stuff you shouldn't care about where it lives -- Python knows where it is and it can find the modules.  Sort of like issuing the command `ls` -- where does `ls` live?  `/usr/bin`?  `/bin`?  99% of the time, you don't need to care -- Just use `ls` and be happy that it lives somewhere on your `PATH` so the shell can find it.
4. I'm not sure I understand the question.  3rd party modules usually come with install instructions.  If you follow the instructions, python should be able to find the module and you shouldn't have to care about where it got installed.
5. Configure `PYTHONPATH` to include the directory where your module resides and python will be able to find your module.

Comment: If a Python user has Python2.7, Python3.5 and Python3.6 installed in Ubuntu, `echo $PYTHONPATH` could return `:/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages`

Answer (score 2):

`PYTHONPATH` is an environment variable those content is added to the `sys.path` where Python looks for modules. You can set it to whatever you like.

However, do **not** mess with `PYTHONPATH`.  More often than not, you are doing it wrong and it will only bring you trouble in the long run. For example, virtual environments could do strange things…

I would suggest you learned [how to package a Python module properly](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages), maybe using [this easy setup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/modern-package-template). If you are especially lazy, you could use [cookiecutter](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter) to do all the hard work for you.

Comment: I suspect the downvotes happens because the question did not address the OP's question directly. It now does. *It is still a terrible idea to mess with `PYTHONPATH`*.