# Python - "No module named my_module" in terminal, but not in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a python script that i'm trying to run.
When i run it from within PyCharm it runs without a problem, but when i run it through the terminal using:

`python my_script.py`

i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "folder/folder/my_script.py", line 4, in <module>
    from my_module import me1, me2, me3
ImportError: No module named my_module
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: One possible explanation is that you are running different versions of python in terminal and in pycharm.

Comment: do you have __init__.py in your module? can you post your directory structure here?

Comment: Both are running the same version of python.
I have `init.py` in the module, and i'll post the directory structure in a bit.

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48532134/python-code-runs-from-ide-but-not-from-terminal/48547472#48547472

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PYTHONPATH in your terminal environment doesn't contain 'my_module'.

[Configure the PYTHONPATH to include the directory containing your module](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html?highlight=pythonpath#envvar-PYTHONPATH)

It works in pycharm because it sets up the path for you automagically.

[Learn about the module search path](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html?highlight=pythonpath#the-module-search-path)

Answer (score 3):

Another reason might be you had started your project in pycharm with virtual enviroment.

If it is the case go to your projects `venv\Scripts` folder via your terminal and run `activate.bat` .

You will see "(venv)" on leftmost in your terminal line. Then go to your project folder and run

`python my_script.py`

Now it should work.

Answer (score 2):

adding the following code to the head of the script did the trick for me:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\path\to\\my\\awesome\\project\\')
```