# PYTHONPATH variable blank

Tags: python, sys.path

According to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html), *sys.path* is initialized from PYTHONPATH when a Python interpreter session starts. However, in my case, PYTHONPATH variable is empty. When I execute this in a terminal:

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

it returns blank. On the other hand, when I start the Python [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop) and inspect *sys.path*:

```
import sys
print (sys.path)
```

I get back a long list of paths. Where do those get loaded from? What am I missing?

Comment: PYTHONPATH is usually undefined or empty

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Check the documentation again](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path):

It says

> [`sys.path` is initialized] from the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`, **plus an installation-dependent default**.

And furthermore,

> the first item of this list, `path[0]`, is the directory containing the script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter [… or] the empty string

That’s why yours isn’t empty.

Comment: Also, some added explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18247492/1832539) on what `PYTHONPATH` is and when to use it. It is up to you to set what you want in that env var for *additional* paths you might want to use.

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate on installation-dependent defaults?

Comment: @Matej Not really: I don’t know exactly where they are configured but most of them are probably hard-coded into the Python configuration during compilation/installation. When installing Python from source you can configure its “prefix” path. That value, in conjunction with relative library path locations, is used to populate `sys.path`.