# ImportError: No module named... After 'sudo pip install..'

Tags: python, pip, installation, sudo, importerror

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325923/how-to-fix-importerror-no-module-named-error-in-python), I have problems importing my own modules and get an `ImportError: No module named ...`.
For example, I have a module at `myfolder/mymodule.py` that I try to load with `from myfolder import mymodule`.

The difference to the other question is that it was working fine before and the problem only occurs on one machine (it works on two other machines). Also I think I know what might have caused the problem: I ran `sudo pip install numpy` to install NumPy. Now, I read that you should never use `sudo` with `pip install`, but it's too late.

Is it possible that `sudo pip install` broke something here? If so, how can I fix it?

So far, I didn't mess with `PYTHONPATH` as suggested by [the top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2326045/2745116) because I also read [that you shouldn't have to touch it when using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18247508/2745116) and I don't want to further break the system.

Just to clarify; `numpy` installed correctly, works and is listed when running `pip freeze`. The problem is really with importing my own module. I don't have a `setup.py` yet. And again, it worked before - so why would I suddenly need to set a variable or path?

Comment: what does `pip freeze` say?

Comment: Instead of `pip install` try `pip3 install`

Comment: `pip freeze` shows all installed packages correctly, including `numpy`. It also gives me a hint to update pip with `pip install --upgrade pip`, which gives me a `Permission denied` when trying to run it. I guess I messed that up when installing with `sudo`?

@Qwerty I updated my question to clarify what I want. There's nothing left to install. `numpy` is also already installed with `pip3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure what suddenly caused the problem (if it was really caused by using `sudo pip install`).

Anyway, I fixed it by [properly packaging my code with a `setup.py`](https://the-hitchhikers-guide-to-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/creation.html) and then installing it with `sudo python3 setup.py develop`. Didn't work without sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure the path to your Python/ Anaconda installation is added to your user path environment variable? I had a similar problem and fixed it once I did that

Comment: Why would I suddenly have to add it if it worked correctly before?