# Set python path variable in Linux Mint for Intellij Idea

Tags: python, linux, pip, linux-mint

What does it mean I install some python package by pip in Linux Mint, installed here: /home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages

```
user@user-H370M-DS3H:~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages$ pip3 show selenium
Name: selenium
Version: 3.141.0
Summary: Python bindings for Selenium
Home-page: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/
Author: UNKNOWN
Author-email: UNKNOWN
License: Apache 2.0
**Location: /home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages**
```

But in Intellij Idea project interpretter cannot recognize this package:
In Project Structure I see only path: **/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages** with some others packages:

And the path **/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages** Intellij Idea does't find. So all the python packages I install throw PIP in Linux console cannot recognize in Intellij Idea.
How can I install python packages by Linux console without using Virtual Env for all projects?

Answer (score 0):

If you set your pythonpath to point to the python IntelliJ knows about (pythonpath explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247333/pythonpath-on-linux)) then pip will install the selenium package to the right location.

At that point you are doing about half the work of a virtual environment though, so you should reconsider why you don't want to use virtual environments for every project.

Comment: I set PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Then make pip install selenium
Then pip show selenium
....
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
Intellij Idea cannot recognize it again..